# Достать сообщение об ошибке с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Добрый день. Имеется следующий тест:

```
Oracle error: -20001;
Oracle error message: ORA-20001: Номер договора должен содержать более трех 
символов или используйте параметр "Страховой продукт."
Oracle stack trace:
```

Помогите составить паттерн, который достанет только:

```
Номер договора должен содержать более трех 
символов или используйте параметр "Страховой продукт."
```

Comment: Надо понять что еще бывает после сообщения кроме "Oracle stack trace". Если в сообщениях об ошибке не может содержаться слова Oracle, то конечно можно попробовать ориентироваться на него, что то вроде `ORA-20001: (.*?)\s+Oracle`, при условии, что вы в приложениях используете только номер 20001

Comment: Я бы включил код ошибки в сообщение, то есть  `/^Oracle error message:\s*(.*)$/mi` потому что если все ошибки в системе имеют описание- это хорошо, но если ошибка не будет иметь описание, то будет возвращен только её код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var s = `Oracle error: -20001;
Oracle error message: ORA-20001: Номер договора должен содержать более трех 
символов или используйте параметр "Страховой продукт."
Oracle stack trace:`

console.log(s.match(/Oracle error message:\s*([\s\S]+)\s+Oracle stack trace:/)[1])
console.log(s.match(/Oracle error message:\s*[^:]+:\s*([\s\S]+)\s+Oracle stack trace:/)[1])
```